# How can I determine or tell if a set of classes is "spaghetti code"?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture

How can I determine or tell if a set of classes are "spaghetti code"?

Should I look at my code as being spaghetti when I generate a Dependency Graph in Visual Studio under the Architecture menu, and see that there are a lot of curvy arrows pointing all over the place?

I always avoid the problem of spaghetti code by attempting to reduce the amount of dependencies between the classes. When doing so, yes, the Dependency Graph indeed becomes neater. And when I make changes to certain part, because the classes have little dependency between each other, I don't have to worry about messing up the other classes.

But, by doing this method, sometimes, it appears that I have to repeat some code. For example, I could have the following object that's stored in a list:

```
class DataBlock {
   public int id;
   public string name;
   public SomeObject dataObj;

   public Object[] Data1 { get { return dataObj.RetrieveInfo(); } }

   public Object[] Data2 { get { return dataObj.SomeProperty; } }

   public bool DoCompare(obj) { ... }
}
```

So, there is a list called `DataList` of the type `List<DataBlock>` consisting the above object.

And then now, suppose I am going to dispatch an event that will include some information from `DataBlock`. I could include this whole `DataBlock` object into the `EventArgs`. The handler function can then just do this:

```
void Handler(MyEventArgs evtArgs) {
   DataBlock data = evtArgs.Data;
   var firstData = data.Data1;
   data.Data2;
   firstData.DoCompare(data.Data2)
   data.name;  //etc, etc
}
```

This is convenient. But, this would also mean that the class that has this handler will then now have dependencies on the `DataBlock` object. So, one of my ways to get rid of this, is within my `EventArgs`, I *repeat* all those informations from `DataBlock`, like this:

```
class MyEventArgs : EventArgs {

   public MyEventArgs(id, name, data1, data2) {
      ID = id;
      Name = name;
      Data1 = data1;
      Data2 = data2;
   }
   public int ID { get; private set; }
   public string name { get; private set; }
   public Object[] Data1 { get; private set; }
   public Object[] Data2  { get; private set; }
}
```

By arranging my `EventArgs` this way, both my `EventArgs` and whichever class having the event `Handler` will not have dependency on the `DataBlock`. Only the firer of the event knows about the `DataBlock` and it rips off the data from `DataBlock` and put them into `MyEventArgs` via its constructor. However, now, the problem in this is, the `MyEventArgs` is *repeating* every getters/setters that is inside `Datablock`. **And, I also lose access to all helper methods within `DataBlock`!**

This is just a small example of a problem that I often face. There are more serious ones where I found myself repeating the getters/settings for a few classes, just because I want to reduce the dependency.

Other problems that I face that show up a lot of arrows on the Dependency Graph, is when, say, I have an interface called `ISomeObject`. Because the `ISomeObject` is a popular object within the classes, the interface is used by many other parts of the classes. In the end, there are tons of arrows pointing to the `ISomeObject`. Would this imply spaghetti code too?

It's difficult for me to explain the problems I face when I want to keep my code organised. But I hope the examples above are enough to illustrate what I want to tell.

So, what are the best practices for a scenario like this? Should I determine that my code is spaghetti when the Dependency Graph in Visual Studio shows a lot of messy curvy arrows pointing all over the place?

Comment: To avoid the getters/setters, I would create interfaces for them, implement the interface in the class, and only use the interface in the eventargs.
And no, I do not think a dependency on an interface is a sign of spaghetti code.

Comment: @Maarten, Thanks! So, I would implement an interface in `DataBlock`, say `IAttributes`, and `IAttributes` has all the getters/setters/helper methods. The concrete implementation of the interface will still be in `Datablock`, but when passed to the `EventArgs`, I pass `IAttributes` instead. This way, `EventArgs` and `DataBlock` will both depend on `IAttributes`, but it's ok to have heavy dependency on interfaces. Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly believe that spaguetti code ins't something tied to dependencies or such higher level things.

Spaguetti code is an anti-pattern that consists on creating a highly-coupled code with no order and completely irrational, meaning that author - programmer(s) - will hardly explain code flow for you.

One of most important symptoms of spaguetti code is that it's unmaintainable: *if you fix a bug, it creates one or more bugs. When you fix these bugs, you get more bugs.* And finally code is fixed by hardcoding garbage everywhere.

Again, I doubt that a *large object graph with a lot of dependencies* would be "spaguetti code".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading NDepend WhiteBooks and documentation.

Take a look at *Code Structure, Design, Dependencies* section here:
http://www.ndepend.com/Tips.aspx#Design